# Getting result from Task.Run

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

Hi guys i'm trying to get some results from Task.Run but i cannot figure it how

I have multiple methods that i would like to run in parallel and extract result:
This is one of the methods

```
protected override async Task<IList<EducationDTO>> GetEmployeesEducation(int userId)
{
    IList<EducationDTO> userEducation = await EducationService.GetEducationsByUserId(userId);        
    return userEducation.Count > 0 ? userEducation : null;
}
```

Here where all methods will be run in parallel

```
public async Task<DTOs.EmployeeDTO> GetEmployeeInfo(int userId)
{
    EmployeeDTO employee = new EmployeeDTO();

    Task task = Task.Run(() => {
        Parallel.Invoke(
        async () => { await GetEmployeeLanguages(userId); },
        // ...
    });
    task.Wait();

    /// extract result and process how ???

    return employee;
}
```

Comment: Why not simply call `var result = await EducationService.GetEducationsByUserId(userId);` ?

Comment: @bash.d His `GetEmployeesEducation` method isn't async. Although it probably should be.

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne Thank you, didn't see that. But it would make sense to do so, I presume.

Comment: hi, yes i could do this , but i chose not to , at this point i just want to see different approaches compare performance and etc

Comment: Performance on this type of thing is going to be negligible, even if you have several unnecessary calls, which you don't. You're fine allowing `async` to propagate up the chain.

Comment: ok assuming that now the code will be all running async i will still have to deal with getting the result from the await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { ...}); which i still don't know how to . if i do something like store the result in a <var task = Task.Factory.StartNew (... )> . trying to do Task.Result is not possible. so how can i return the result collected from all of the methods that run in parallel

Comment: I don't see any parallelism here - you're only calling it once. Also, why do Task,Run() and then Parallel.Invoke inside? 
Why not declare IList<EducationDTO result; just before Task task and assign await GetEmployeeLanguages(userId);

Comment: It's *better* to return an empty `IList<EducationDTO>` than null. You could replace your method with `return EducationService.GetEducationsByUserId..` and save yourself the null checks further on. No need to use `await` either when returning the task directly

Comment: What do the service methods do? Are they calling the same database or connection? If they do, you are going to get *worse* performance, compared eg to loading all related objects with a single call

Comment: Not directly related to your question but using any of the methods with `Parallel` and async await is not supported at all, your functions will be treated as `async void` functions and you will get unexpected behavior. Switch to using [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx) or don't use `async () =>` with the functions in the `Parallel` class.

Answer (score 1):

> I have multiple methods that i would like to run in parallel and extract result

Actually, you want to run them *concurrently*. "Parallel" implies CPU-bound code, but your code is I/O-bound.

So, don't use `Parallel` at all; it's the wrong tool here:

```
public async Task<DTOs.EmployeeDTO> GetEmployeeInfo(int userId)
{
  EmployeeDTO employee = new EmployeeDTO();

  // Start all tasks
  var languagesTask = GetEmployeeLanguages(userId);
  var educationsTask = GetEmployeesEducation(userId);
  var outExperiencesTask = GetEmployeesOutExperience(userId);
  var ubiExperiencesTask = GetEmployeesUbiExperience(userId);

  // Asynchronously wait for them all to complete
  await Task.WhenAll(languagesTask, educationsTask, outExperiencesTask, ubiExperiencesTask);

  // Retrieve results
  employee.Languages = await languagesTask;
  employee.Educations = await educationsTask;
  employee.OutExperiences = await outExperiencesTask;
  employee.UbiExperiences = await ubiExperiencesTask;

  return employee;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no use creating a task and immediately waiting for it, so drop the `StartNew`.

Also no need to first `Wait` and then fetch the `Result`, `Result` implicitly waits. And the method isn't asynchronous at all and you can drop `async Task<>` and directly return the `EmployeeDTO`...

Answer (score -2):

So this is my finding

```
public async Task<DTOs.EmployeeDTO> GetEmployeeInfo(int userId)
{

    EmployeeDTO employee = new EmployeeDTO();

    Task<EmployeeDTO> task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Parallel.Invoke(
         () => { employee.Languages = GetEmployeeLanguages(userId).Result; },
         () => { employee.Educations = GetEmployeesEducation(userId).Result; },
         () => { employee.OutExperiences = GetEmployeesOutExperience(userId).Result; },
         () => { employee.UbiExperiences = GetEmployeesUbiExperience(userId).Result; });

        return employee;
    });
    task.Wait();

    return task.Result;

}
```

If you have any other suggestions, or a better approach please share. Thank you.

Comment: lookup `Task.WhenAll` and use it instead of the parallel invoke

Comment: Why use Parallel.Invoke when you already have all your tasks at hand? Just use `await Task.WhenAll(langTask, eduTask,...);`. Then get each completed task's Result. Each time you think you need `Wait` or `.Result` you should consider that you are actually doing something wrong

Comment: Are you calling a database or web service? In both cases it would be faster (a lot) to return all related objects in a single call instead of trying to load them "in parallel". Such calls are usually dominated by network latencies. You'll spend the *same* time but cause greater contention on the server, and probably query/load the same table rows 4 times